# All possible combinations of values in two lists

Tags: apex, class, list

I have two lists, let's do:

```
L1 = {A, B, C}
L2 = {A1, C1, C2}
```

List L2 contains duplicates of values in list L1.
Each value in List L1 can have one duplicate in list L2 (as "A" and "A1" in the e.g.), more duplicates (as "C", "C1" and "C2") or none (as "B").

What I need is to create a new List L3 containing all possible combinations obtained by replacing each value in L1 with its duplicate in L2.
In this case, the possible combinations are:

```
A, B, C
A, B, C1
A, B, C2
A1, B, C
A1, B, C1
A1, B, C2
```

I always miss some combinations in my algorithms, do you have any suggestions (also using Maps instead of lists, or stuff like this)?
Hope my question is clear enough, Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty, but here is some anonymous Apex using recursion to get you started.

```
List<string> L1 = new List<string>{'A', 'B', 'C'};
List<string> L2 = new List<string>{'A1', 'C1', 'C2'};

Map<String, Set<String>> permsMap = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
for(string key : L1) {
    permsMap.put(key, new Set<string>{key});
}
System.debug(permsMap);

for(string key2 : L2) {
    string prefix = key2.substring(0, 1);
    System.debug(prefix);
    Set<string> existingList = permsMap.get(prefix);
    if(!existingList.contains(key2)) {
        existingList.add(key2);
    }
}
System.debug(permsMap);

List<string> results = new List<string>();

recursion(permsMap, new Set<string>(), results, '', 0);

for(string value : results) {
    System.debug(value);
}

// Anonymous Apex Method for performing recursion
void recursion(Map<String, Set<String>> permsMap, Set<string> processedKeysParam, List<string> results, string currentProgress, integer depth) {

    Set<string> processedKeys = new Set<string>();
    processedKeys.addAll(processedKeysParam);

    boolean termination = depth == permsMap.keySet().size();

    for(string prefix : permsMap.keySet()) {
        if(processedKeys.contains(prefix)) {
            continue;
        }
        termination = false;

        processedKeys.add(prefix);

        Set<string> existingSet = permsMap.get(prefix);

        for(string value : existingSet) {

            System.debug('Processing: ' + value + ' currentProgress:' + currentProgress);

            string result = currentProgress;        
            if(result.length() > 0) {
                result += ', ';
            }
            result += value;

            recursion(permsMap, processedKeys, results, result, depth+1);
        }   
    }

    if(termination) {
        // Reached the deepest point in the recursion, so stop processing and add result
        results.add(currentProgress);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> A, B, C
>   A, B, C1
>   A, B, C2
>   A1, B, C
>   A1, B, C1
>   A1, B, C2

A few points:

1. The inner Sets on the `permsMap` aren't ideal as they don't have a defined ordering like a `List<string>` would. They should really be lists to ensure the ordering doesn't get messed up. I only went with Sets here to get quicker access to the contains method.
2. I didn't really want to be creating a new `processedKeys` Set instance for each recursive call. Again, it was the quickest way to track the processed keys at each level. It would likely be more efficient to have a single Set and then push and pop the keys as you move up and down the recursive methods.
3. There is probably a better way to detecting leaf nodes then tracking the current `depth`. Expedience lead me to just pass the parameter down and then add the result when the maximum depth was reached.